# Cartan combination in the fundamental representation of SU(N)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics

On page 6 of [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0008035) paper by Diakonov and Petrov, it is stated that the Cartan combination,
$$
\sum_im_iH_i,
$$
($m_i$ are elements of a highest weight) in the fundamental representation can always be set to
$$
\textrm{diag}(1,0,\ldots,0)
$$
by rotating the axes and subtracting the ”unit” matrix which I understand as the identity matrix.

My questions are, how does one show this in general, and why are we allowed to subtract the identity matrix here?

For SU(2), $\textbf{m}=(1)$ in the fundamental representation and since $$H=
\bigg(\begin{array} (1 \ \ \ \ \ 0 \\ 0 \ -1\end{array}\bigg), $$
subtracting the identity matrix gives me
$$\bigg(\begin{array} (0 \ \ \ \ \ 0 \\ 0 \ -2\end{array}\bigg) $$

This is close to to the expected answer if we rotate the axis, and rescale by -2.

But I still do not get why the identity matrix can be subtracted?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/726972/cartan-combination-in-fundamental-representation-of-sun

Comment: It says the "unit" matrix, not the identity matrix. But perhaps this is the same. Also, they consider $SU(N)/SU(N-1)$, and "higher groups", so not $SU(2)/SU(1)$, etc. You should copy all the ten lines into your post for better context.